# How to convert WebAnno Name Entity annotation to use in OpenNLP?

Tags: nlp, opennlp, dkpro-core, webanno

Based in this issue I need to export in XMI format and use DKPro Core to convert to Brat format:

https://github.com/webanno/webanno/issues/328

I tried this code but did not have success

```
public void convert() throws Exception {

    SimplePipeline.runPipeline(CollectionReaderFactory
            .createReaderDescription(XmiReader.class, XmiReader.PARAM_SOURCE_LOCATION, "/tmp", XmiReader.PARAM_PATTERNS,
                    XmiReader.INCLUDE_PREFIX + "*.xmi"), AnalysisEngineFactory
              .createEngineDescription(BratWriter.class, BratWriter.PARAM_TARGET_LOCATION, "/tmp"));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *dialect* of the brat format may be different between what the DKPro Core BratWriter produces and what OpenNLP expects - the brat file format is quite flexible.

If you are using the built-in *Named Entity* layer in WebAnno, then I would propose an alternative route:

- Stay with the XMI export
- Load the XMI with DKPro Core 1.9.0-SNAPSHOT and feed it to the `OpenNlpNamedEntityRecognizerTrainer` component

That should avoid the need for the additional conversion step.

*Disclosure:* I am a WebAnno and DKPro Core developer.

Suggestions that didn't work:

- Export as `CoNLL 2002` in WebAnno
- [OpenNLP supports training the NER tool directly from CoNLL 2002 files](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training.tool).
- => The `Conll02NameSampleStream` supports only certain languages and named entity types... *sigh*

Comment: Thanks for awser, but I use other TagSet from this layer.

Comment: OpenNLP CoNLL 2002 suport only Spa and Nld Langs and only 4 types (per,loc,org,misc). https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/manual/opennlp.html#tools.cli.namefind.TokenNameFinderConverter

Comment: Alternative suggestion: you could use the OpenNlpNamedEntityRecognizerTrainer component from the upcoming DKPro Core 1.9.0 which is right is already available in 1.9.0-SNAPSHOT builds.

Comment: For my purposes, I need other categories for my business area. For example, think  extract animals or Titles of books cited in my texts.
Or a wrong way of use NER for detecting simple intentions, like "walk the dog" and "play with the cat" in the category Hobby, and "wash the car" or "cut the grass" in the category Work.

Comment: I will try this new solution. Thanks.